# Load media thumbnails efficiently

Tags: java, android, multithreading, image

I've spent few days to solve this problem but still can't find a solution. I'm new to Android so my code might be pretty messy!

I have a RecyclerView(Grid layout) that displays thumbnails for images and videos. It loads media files in a specific folder. But when I launch this activity, it takes up so much memory!

To load thumbnails, I created two threads.

**Thread 1) MediaLoadThread** that queries media files in SDCard. It loops through the cursor and queue thumbnail decode tasks to the different thread.

**Thread 2) ThumbnailLoaderThread** that decode each individual thumbnail. It receives the content resolver, media type(image or video), and media id. It uses basic .getThumbnail() method. After it's done with getting thumbnail, it triggers the response callback to it's caller thread(MediaLoadThread).

3) When MediaLoadThread(Thread 1) receives the callback, it triggers another callback that lets the activity update the adapter item of the given position. The adapter updates the UI and finally the thumbnail ImageView changes from placeholder to actual thumbnail.

**:::Here's my code:::**

**1) MediaLoadThread.java**

```
@Override
public void run() {
    mMediaDataArr.clear();
    mLoaderThread.start(); // Prepping the thread 2
    mLoaderThread.prepareHandler(); 

      // .... SD Card query stuff .....     

        if (mediaCursor != null && mediaCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                mMediaDataArr.add(new MediaData(videoCursor.getInt(columnIndexId),
                        mediaCursor.getLong(columnIndexDate), //ID
                        mediaCursor.getInt(columnIndexType), //MEDIA TYPE
                        null); //THUMBNAIL BITMAP (NULL UNTIL THE ACTUAL THUMBNAIL IS DECODED)
            } while (mediaCursor.moveToNext());
            mediaCursor.close();
            mResponseHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                // This callback lets the activity activate the adapter and recyclerview so that the user can interact with recyclerview before the app finishes decoding thumbnails. 
                    mCallback.onVideoLoaded(mMediaDataArr); 
                }
            });

            //Passing tasks to thread 2
            for (int i = 0; i < mMediaDataArr.size(); i++) {
                mLoaderThread.queueTask(
                        mMediaDataArr.get(i).getmMediaType(),
                        i, mMediaDataArr.get(i).getmMediaId());
            }
        }
    }
}

// This is triggered by thread 2 when it finishes decoding 
@Override
public void onThumbnailLoaded(final int position, final Bitmap thumbnail) {
        mResponseHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mCallback.onThumbnailPrepared(position, thumbnail);
            }
        });
}
```

**2) ThumbnailLoaderThread.java**

```
public void queueTask(int mediaType, int position, int videoId) {
    mWorkerHandler.obtainMessage(mediaType, position, videoId).sendToTarget();
}

public void prepareHandler() {
    mWorkerHandler = new Handler(getLooper(), new Handler.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            int type = msg.what;
            final int position = msg.arg1;
            int videoId = msg.arg2;
            try {
                if (type == MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
                    Bitmap newThumb = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails
                            .getThumbnail(mCr, videoId,
                                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null);
                    postResult(position, newThumb);

                } else if (type == MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
                    Bitmap newThumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails
                            .getThumbnail(mCr, videoId,
                                    MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null);
                    postResult(position, newThumb);
                } 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}

private void postResult(final int position, final Bitmap newThumb) {
        mResponseHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mCallback.onThumbnailLoaded(position, newThumb);
            }
        });
}
```

**3) LibraryActivity.java**

```
@Override
public void onThumbnailPrepared(int position, Bitmap thumbnail) {
    if (thumbnail != null && position < mData.size()) {
        MediaData updatedData = mData.get(position);
        updatedData.setmThumbnail(thumbnail);
        mData.set(position, updatedData);
        mVideoAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
    }
}
```

The flow is like this.

1) The activity starts the thread 1.

2) Thread 1 starts querying files and starts thread 2. It passes the media id looping through the cursor.

3) Thread 2 decodes thumbnails with the given media id.

4) When decoding is done, thread 2 triggers the callback to Thread 1 with the result bitmap.

5) Thread 1 receives the bitmap and delivers the bitmap to activity through callback.

6) Activity receives the thumbnail and updates the RecyclerView data with the given bitmap.

It works fine, but when the system allocates almost 50MB of memory for this task... Considering it was only loading 100 thumbnails, I think it's pretty heavy.

**:::What I've tried:::**

1) I extracted the URI of each individual thumbnail and let the recyclerview adapter to load the image with the given URI when it binds. It works fine and did not consume that much memory, but because it loads images when the item is bound, it reloads the thumbnail whenever I scroll the screen with a little bit of delay.

2) I let the adapter to load thumbnails with the direct thumbnail path. But it won't work when the user cleans up the /.thumbnails folder.

3) I set the BitmapFactory.Options samplsize into 4 when the thread decodes thumbnails. But when it was still heavy and even slower sometimes...

4) In MediaData object, it holds the thumbnail bitmap as a member variable. So I made it null right after the adapter loaded it into the ImageView. Still heavy, and because I made the object's thumbnail into null, it just shows the placeholder when I scroll back.

I really have no clue. Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can used [nostra universal](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) image loader library to load images. This library is very good for image loading and also some other library like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) etc available which you can used instead of making manual coding.

Comment: I tried using Picasso but it loads the actual images. Not thumbnails. Isn't it too heavy to load the image file itself? :(

Comment: You can resize the image according to your layout size bellow is the code
Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView)

Comment: Thanks. Then where should I add that line? If I add it in my adapter's bindViewHolder method, it will resize images whenever I scroll.

Comment: Okay I added this line on my bindViewHolder method.             Picasso.with(context).load(currentData.getUri()).centerCrop().resize(mWidth, mWidth).into(holder.mThumbnailIV);. Somewhat better. But still loads images whenever it binds items.